# How to put the ID of Google Analytics on my Android App?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have this ID for my GA account: "UA 25832113-1"

ok, but... how I have to put it on my app? Which format?

A -> "UA 25832113-1"

B -> "UA-25832113-1"

C -> "25832113-1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B is correct. (ie. 'UA-10876-1')

Official docs: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts.html#webProperty

Answer (score 1):

B

if you are using the "Google Analytics SDK for Android" you shuld use something like this:

```
tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
tracker.startNewSession("UA-25832113-1", this);
```